# Saving and retrieving inflated View's size in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which has a staggeredGridLayoutManager as layout manager. My layout stands as having 2 spans(cols), which items inside may have different heights.
Inflated items has a ImageView and some other views  inside a LinearLayout container.

I want to save Inflated(or should I say binded?) View's size(height and width) after the view's image is fully loaded. Because this operation makes me know how much width and height the LinearLayout occupy at final-after the image is placed in the layout-.

After scrolling, this container may be recycled and binded again. What I want to achieve is to savebinded layout's size immediately after it is binded, according to the height and width values previously calculated because this makes recyclerView's item positions more stable. They are less likely move around.

I have mWidth and mHeight members in my ViewHolder, which basically store these values. However, I lost syncronisation between item position in adapter and corresponding ViewHolder. For example I calculate height of 8th item as 380px when it first become visible, which is correct. After recycling and binding 8th position again, my view's height retrieved as 300 px, which is incorrect.

Code:
BasicActivity is derived from Activity..

```
public ItemsRVAdapter(BasicActivity activity, JSONArray items){
    this.items = items;
    this.activity = activity;
    this.itemControl = new Items(activity);
}
```

OnCreate:

```
@Override
public ItemListViewHolders onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {


    View layoutView =activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_element_items, viewGroup, false);
    ItemListViewHolders rcv = new ItemListViewHolders(layoutView);
    return rcv;
}
```

OnViewAttachedToWindow (I tried the same code here in different places, like onViewRecycled but I don't know this method is the most right place to calculete the size)

```
@Override
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ItemListViewHolders holder)
{
    holder.layoutCapsule.measure(LinearLayout.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, LinearLayout.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), LinearLayout.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, LinearLayout.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    if(holder.image.getDrawable() != null){

        holder.height = holder.layoutCapsule.getHeight();
        holder.width = holder.layoutCapsule.getWidth();
    }else{
        holder.height = 0;
        holder.width = 0;
    }

}
```

onBindViewHolder: Only relevant part. Here I paired position value and my array's member index

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemListViewHolders holder, int position) {
    try {

        //JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(position);
        holder.image.setImageDrawable(null);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = holder.layoutCapsule; //Main Container
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `GridLayoutManager` or disable the 'shifting around' if you don't want items to move?

Comment: I have 2 spans(columns), but unlike grid, items in Columns may have different heights.

Comment: So why don't you just disable the item shifting with `GAP_HANDLING_NONE`?

Comment: GAP_HANDLING_NONE doesn't disable item shifting, at least not in the way I want or it has a bug. It does shift items even strategy is GAP_HANDLING_NONE, probably only when if items has different heights. You can see my other question here, which has a youtube link showing what I said. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565743/problems-using-recyclerview-with-staggeredlayoutmanager You can see both rows are moving with GAP_HANDLING_NONE, and the gap problem at top in the vide

Comment: I curious of what is your purpose? You can set your RecyclerView to have #setHasFixedSize to **false** if you want your UI is more stable. ViewHolders are recycled anytime, why would you want to remember them. If your ultimate purpose is to disable the item shifting, I guess you should start from your data sorting, image size handling and more.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend looking for a different approach to resolve your problem with the items moving around not depending on View sizes, but if you want to proceed this way this is my proposed solution:

Don't depend or save the size values on the holder as this gets recycled, you will need to create an object "descriptor" with the values (width and height) for each position and save them on a HashMap or something like that, save the values as you are doing it already, i understand on "onViewAttachedToWindow".

```
class Descriptor(){
   int width;
   int height;

void setWidth(int width){
   this.width = width;
}
int getWidth(){
   return width;
}
void setHeight(int height){
   this.height = height;
}
int getHeight(){
   return height;
}
```

Initialize array on constructor:

```
descriptors = new HashMap<Integer, Descriptor>();
```

in onBindViewHolder save the position on a view tag to use it on OnViewAttachedToWindow

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemListViewHolders holder, int position) {
   ....
   holder.image.setTag(position);
   ...
}
```

populate values on onViewAttachedToWindow

```
public void onViewAttachedToWindow(ItemListViewHolders holder){
   ...
   int position = (Integer)holder.image.getTag();
   Descriptor d = descriptors.get(position);
   if(d == null){
      d = new Descriptor();
      descriptors.put(position, d);
   }
   d.setWidth(holder.layoutCapsule.getWidth());
   d.setHeight(holder.layoutCapsule.getHeight());
   ...
}
```

Then use the size data on the descriptor on the method you need getting it by position, you will be creating descriptors as the user is scrolling down, also this works on the asumption that the data maintains the same position during the life of the adapter.

Comment: onViewAttachedToWindow sometimes doesn't give correct height. It just gives previous pre-recycled height.